Does pursuing Masters makes sense for a person with a decade of professional experience
So I've been in the industry of 10 years, specifically software development. Recently, I've decided to pursue my masters in computer science and gotten admitted in a program. However, I still don't have a clear purpose. I want to do it but I still don't know why. Getting masters won't boost my career and I don't want to get into academics or pursue Phd.
Does it make sense to you, investing this much time and money just because you feel like it?

Absolutely. You only have one life. If there is something that you want to do, and it might be beneficial and isn't harmful then Just Do It.
People do all sorts of things because they just "feel like it". If it isn't harmful or particularly burdensome, there isn't really any reason not to do it.
Lots of people in doctoral programs, in fact, are just there because they want to be, and are willing to let practical concerns wait while they explore some field deeply. And, I'd answer the same if you were thinking of, say, a philosophy degree.
Life is short. Don't waste it.

Indeed, many things only need to make sense to you yourself.

Thank you, I've decided not to overthink this one :)
